# org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: ARERR [149] A user name must be supplied in the control record

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, soap

Hi everyone I need one help.

I am writing the wrapper top of the wsdl.

**My SOAPUI- Request is :-**

I need to send my request like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:UET_CMContacts_WS">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
         <urn:userName>test</urn:userName>
         <urn:password>test</urn:password>
      </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:opGetContacts>
         <urn:Qualification>LoginName="TEST"</urn:Qualification>
         <urn:startRecord>0</urn:startRecord>
         <urn:maxLimit>20</urn:maxLimit>
      </urn:opGetContacts>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my Java Code

```
        UETCMContactsWSService service1 = new UETCMContactsWSService();
        service1.setHandlerResolver(new SOAPHandlerResolver());
        ContactDetailsPortType port1 = service1.getContactDetailsSoap();

        AuthenticationInfo authInfo = new AuthenticationInfo();
        authInfo.setUserName(uetRequestParameters.getUserName());
        authInfo.setPassword(uetRequestParameters.getPassword());

        Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)port1).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, uetRequestParameters.getUserName());  
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, uetRequestParameters.getPassword());  
        requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, requestContext);    

        InputMapping1 inputMap = new InputMapping1();
        inputMap.setQualification(uetRequestParameters.getQualification());
        inputMap.setStartRecord(uetRequestParameters.getStartRecord());
        inputMap.setMaxLimit(uetRequestParameters.getMaxLimit());

         List<GetListValues>  getListValue= port1.opGetContacts(
                 inputMap.getQualification(),
                 inputMap.getStartRecord(),
                 inputMap.getMaxLimit());
```

while using this code when i am looking my response in SOAPHandler

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <soap:Body>
        <opGetContacts xmlns="urn:UET_CMContacts_WS">
            <Qualification>VKUMARRA</Qualification>
            <startRecord>0</startRecord>
            <maxLimit>20</maxLimit>
        </opGetContacts>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and also i am getting the exception:-

```
12:50:15,924 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/UETProfile].[Resteasy]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: ARERR [149] A user name must be supplied in the control record
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:365) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: ARERR [149] A user name must be supplied in the control record
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.opGetContacts(Unknown Source)
    at com.cox.etadirect.rs.route.GetUetProfileWS.startRoute(GetUetProfileWS.java:90) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
```

Anyone has any idea about this where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things in your code which I think don't correspond to your request. For example as you said you want to add the follow xml fragment inside your `soap:Header`

```
<soap:Header>
   <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
      <urn:userName>test</urn:userName>
      <urn:password>test</urn:password>
   </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
</soap:Header>
```

As I see in your code you're creating this structure:

```
AuthenticationInfo authInfo = new AuthenticationInfo();
authInfo.setUserName(uetRequestParameters.getUserName());
authInfo.setPassword(uetRequestParameters.getPassword());
```

However in your code you define it but not assign it in `soap:Header` request.

Also you are trying to add and `http heades` for `http basic authentication` which I think it's not necessary for your WS (at least you don't say it in your question):

```
Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)port1).getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, uetRequestParameters.getUserName());  
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, uetRequestParameters.getPassword());  
requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, requestContext);
```

I think that the solution is simply put `authInfo` in the `soap:Header` as the WS expects.

Hope this helps,